# Check if data entered by user in html form already exists in database in php

Tags: php, mysql

After entering data in html form while clicking on button to add the data in the database, I want to check whether the user already exists in the database. I am using php v5.3.5 and mysql v5.5.8.
Data is stored in 2 tables simultaneously named person and other and there is no primary key(in both columns) since there is no column which can be treated as primary key
Can any one help me how to do that??

Code is::

```
$sqlComm="Insert into person(Name,father_name,date_birth,
gender,Res_Address,Mobile_no)
  values('$name','$fatherName','$dob',
 '$gender1','$resAddress','$mobileNo')";
$sql="insert into other_staff(p_id,employer,off_ph_no) 
      values('$pId','$employer1','$phOffice')";
```

Id is automatically generated for each person which is retrieved and stored in other table as p_id.
combination of name,father_name,date_birth,employer can be made unique..

Comment: `no primary key`, mate, you need to reconsider your schema!!

Comment: @NoobEditor I think OP have `auto_incremented` Primary Key look at `p_id` inserted into `other_staff` may be a foreign key referring to `person`

Comment: `p_id` does nothing for duplicates @VedantTerkar. It cant tell whether its the same person or a new one.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, Yup You're right OP should have `Mobile_no` and `pid` as `Primary key`. May be that can help. Right?

Comment: @VedantTerkar : `$pid` is passed for `pid`...its not auto incremented mate!! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like none of the fields suggested can be a primary key, any of them or a combination of them cannot uniquely identify a person. It's a really strange database design and I urge you to check your database design.

You will have to a search by doing a separate select query to find if the user exists. Also Ensure both the statements are executed inside a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to think about what makes a person unique for your schema/application. Changing the mobile number probably does not make one a new person, but am i the same as an existing person, if we share the name, father_name, date_birth and gender? If so, make that a unique key and you will have something your database can tell you, that it already exists. Just in case you did not already know: keys can span multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Dispite with a bad schema, we can find a way(given below) to check weather a user exist or not. BUT I think you also want to check second table THAT with particular user there is an employer or not. Then here is problem in your database cause there is no column in PERSON **or** OTHER_STAFF's table which can tell us the **Particular *employer* of a specific user in PERSON table**

**Solution:** But for this condition you can use cross join to get nearly correct result:

```
    if($result=mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM person p CROSS JOIN other_staff e WHERE p.name='$name' AND p.father_name='$father_name' AND p.date_birth='$dob' AND p.gender='$gender1' AND p.Res_Address='$resAddress' AND p.Mobile_no='$mobileNo' AND e.employer='$employer1' AND e.off_ph_no='$phOff';")){
           if(mysql_fetch_array($result)){
              //exist
           }else{
             //not exist
           }
    }
```

---

**Suggestion:** Next time store auto generated id in PERSON and OTHER STAFF table **BUT for this project-**  If you can store `p_id` in PERSON table then this query will return 1 on exist, otherwise null(same in above):

```
     $sql="SELECT 1 FROM person p LEFT JOIN other_staff e ON p.p_id=e.p_id WHERE p.name='$name' AND p.father_name='$father_name' AND p.date_birth='$dob' AND p.gender='$gender1' AND p.Res_Address='$resAddress' AND p.Mobile_no='$mobileNo' AND e.employer='$employer1' AND e.off_ph_no='$phOff';";
```